# Eclipse's quick access equivalent in Intellij

Tags: intellij-idea

Do you know anything similar to Eclipse's quick access (ctrl+3) in Intellij? Tried to google but with no result. There is description of this feature: http://techvj.blogspot.com/2007/11/any-software-developer-using-ide-begins.html

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Main Menu | Search | Find Action (Ctrl+Shift+A)

Comment: yep looks like thats all I can get but actually I prefer the way Eclipse organize it. It's much more detailed so knowing ctr+3 you can get rid of mouse:) thanks.